# Python set deduplication comparison

Tags: python, set

**Problem:** I have multiple sets (in Python) which I want to compare with each other whether they are equal or not. As output I only want to keep the "unique" sets. (All sets have the same number of elements in it but number of sets can differ).
Any idea how to do this efficiently?

```
s1 = {"A", "B", "C"}
s2 = {"F", "G", "H"}
s3 = {"A", "B", "C"}
s4 = {"F", "G", "I"}
s5 = {"F", "G", "H"}

# output should be "unique" sets s1, s2, s4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using a `set` if you convert your sets to `frozenset` objects. So given:

```
>>> s1 = {"A", "B", "C"}
>>> s2 = {"F", "G", "H"}
>>> s3 = {"A", "B", "C"}
>>> s4 = {"F", "G", "I"}
>>> s5 = {"F", "G", "H"}
```

Then just:

```
>>> set(map(frozenset, [s1, s2, s3, s4, s5]))
{frozenset({'G', 'I', 'F'}), frozenset({'B', 'C', 'A'}), frozenset({'G', 'H', 'F'})}
```

Answer (score 0):

A set cannot contain sets, but it can contain `frozenset` instances.

```
set_list = [s1, s2, s3, s4, s5]
temp = set(frozenset(s) for s in set_list)
uniqs = list(set(s) for s in resul)
print(uniqs)
```

It gives as expected:

```
[{'C', 'A', 'B'}, {'G', 'H', 'F'}, {'G', 'I', 'F'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import itertools
s1 = {"A", "B", "C"}
s2 = {"F", "G", "H"}
s3 = {"A", "B", "C"}
s4 = {"F", "G", "I"}
s5 = {"F", "G", "H"}
list_sets = [list(s1), list(s2), list(s3), list(s4), list(s5)]
list_sets.sort()
new_list = list(list_sets for list_sets,_ in itertools.groupby(list_sets))
for item in new_list:
    print(item)
```

I referred it from here:
https://www.w3resource.com/python-exercises/list/python-data-type-list-exercise-69.php